# Microseconds unix time integer as a string in PHP

Tags: php, time

I need the current unixtime as a round number of microseconds in a string. There's a chance the code could run on a machine with 32 bit integers so I'd beter avoid ints. The value is used only in SQL queries, so a string will be fine.

Is it safe to use the following code?

```
$x = explode(' ', microtime());
$y = $x[1] . substr($x[0], 2, 6);
```

Is it safe to assume the coordinates of these substrings in microtime()'s return value are invariant?

Comment: Why you need a UNIX-timestamp with such a high precision?

Comment: Why do you cut the msec apart?

Comment: @KingCrunch: to be able to maintain a record of the order of arrival of messages at a server more accurately than without one-second granularity. I'm aware that the method isn't perfect but it's an improvement and easy.

Comment: @hakre: I decided to store the value in the database as a `bigint(20)` for efficiency's sake and to enable sorting and handle it in PHP as a string.

Comment: @fsb: I think ensuring the order with a simple `AUTO INCREMENT`-column (in conclusion with atomic operations/transaction) would be the "most" accurate. You can now argue, that two `INSERT`-queries _exactly_ at the same time may be inserted in "random order", but you will get the same problem with `microtime()` (and I don't see, where such a high precision feels useful instead just saying "both come in at the same time").

Comment: @KingCrunch: an AI column wouldn't **also** be a unix timestamp. I didn't say message ordering was the only use for the timestamp. I answered why I wanted a high precision one. There's plenty people think MySQL's lack of microsecond timestamp is a bug that should have been fixed years ago, including the Drizzle folk who made their timstamps 64-bit microseconds by default. It really has a lot of uses.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Is it safe to assume the coordinates of these substrings in microtime()'s return value are invariant?

Yes it is, pretty much. The string return value is there since longer time an preserved. One proposed change is to make the optional argument defaulting true, however, then you can set it to false to get the string.

Comment: So using `microtime(false)` would perhaps be a bit safer.

Answer (score 0):

It's [documented as such](http://php.net/manual/en/function.microtime.php) in the PHP manual, so as long as you trust that PHP won't starting breaking backward compatibility any time soon, then yes, you can trust this.

> By default, microtime() returns a string in the form "msec sec", where sec is the current time measured in the number of seconds since the Unix epoch (0:00:00 January 1, 1970 GMT), and msec is the number of microseconds that have elapsed since sec expressed in seconds.
>
> If get_as_float is set to TRUE, then microtime() returns a float, which represents the current time in seconds since the Unix epoch accurate to the nearest microsecond.

---

**Edit** nevermind, I misunderstood.

Comment: In my reading, the manual is at odds with PHP's behavior right here. I get `string(21) "0.35134900 1310425828"` in which `0.35134900` is  evidently **not** "the number of microseconds that have elapsed since sec expressed in seconds". But perhaps it's more likely that the manual will be fixed than the code.

Comment: @fsb: mind **expressed in seconds** and mind **since sec**. The documentation looks pretty valid to me. Msec will never be one or larger.

Comment: @hakre: oh my goodness. I finally see what you mean. That kind of tortured construction should be considered a crime against the language. It was beyond my imagination that "expressed in seconds" modifies "the number of microseconds" rather than "sec" that it immediately follows. And "The number of microseconds expressed in seconds" is an odd way to say "fraction of a second". Thanks for deciphering this.

Comment: @fsb: Good we spoke about it ;)